# Android Map Custom info window with box shape on bottom in Clusterer

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow, markerclusterer

I need to make custom info window for my android application; like below. Please see the image below.

This info window appears when user clicked on the marker. It can show on the top of the map or on the bottom of the map according marker position.

I don't have idea to make this. I have explored stackoverflow, many ways to create custom info windows, but for this one, I haven't found any solution here. So, can somebody tell me how to build that?

[image]

Comment: plz post your java code for custom dialog ..

Comment: @DileepPatel I don't have any idea to make this. That's why I have posted this question

Comment: The dialog which you presented in your screenshot, you don't need info window, as info window normally used to show aligntop of the map pin. you could easily create custom view and popup it when user will click any map pin!

Comment: @Efficient you can see my custom dialog window code in below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set programmatically custom window by this code..onClick of your button

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(this);
Window window = dialog1.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM; // Here you can set window top or bottom
wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.openYourWindow, null);
dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog1.setContentView(view1);
dialog1.show();
```

Comment: I wroks but a problem is that half dialog is showing in bottom

Comment: I think problem in your xml code you can check to set your layout height with  match_parent or wrap_content

Comment: It look like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzIMMfIUt-fJSTd4b2FEX3NHZEk/view?usp=sharing)  `layout_marginBottom` not working

Comment: @ Efficient You can set your main linear layout height and width are match parent and inside another linear layout set height and width are wrap_content..

Comment: Please up vote My Question Because there is no any other question on this problem on stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

You should make the custom layout.

```
<FrameLayout>
....
<MapFragment/>

<FrameLayout (match_parent, match_parent) ... android:id="@+id/my_info_window_wrapper"/>

<LinearLayout...
android:id="@+id/my_info_window"
 android:visibility = "gone">

<ImageView../>
<TextView../>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout >
```

and in code

```
mViewWrapper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickLister{
 mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
)};

GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener{
  mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
)};
```